# Why is the return of this method getting destructed?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class mini
{
  public:
  mini() { cout << "mini()";  }
  ~mini() { cout << "~mini()"; }
};
class test
{
  public:
  mini ret()
  {
    return *(new mini());
  }
};
int main()
{
  test a;
  a.ret();
  cout << "end of block";
}
```

Output:

```
mini()~mini()end of block
```

Why is ~mini() run here before the end of the block? Or rather at all... If I change the output of the method to mini* then it doesn't get removed. I understand stack objects do get deleted, but I'm new'ing here.

Comment: Please stop using `new` in c++, unless you're absolutely a 200% sure what you're doing. **C++, `new`/`delete` YAGNI!!**

Comment: `return *(new mini());` returns a copy of the mini as an r-value, which is not being stored, destructing when `a.ret();` completes. The original, spawned in the function, is a memory leak.

Comment: I think people need to consider that this isn't production code and serves the purpose of illustrating the question. `return  *new T()` hurts the eyes but it clearly explains what the question is asking which is : where is the extra `mini` destruction coming from.

Comment: Might be helpful in the constructor & destructor to add in `<< (void*)this` to make it more visible the object being constructed & destructed.

Answer (score 8):

Consider what happens here

```
  mini ret()
  {
    return *(new mini());
  }
```

`ret()` is a function returning `mini` by-value.

`new mini()` allocates `mini` on the heap. `return *(new mini());` returns a copy of it by-value. So what is printed is the construction of `mini` on the heap and a destruction of its copy on the stack at the end of the full-expression where `ret()` is called.

To visualize it, implement a copy constructor:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class mini
{
public:
    mini() { cout << "mini()\n"; }
    mini(const mini&) { cout << "mini() copy\n"; }
    ~mini() { cout << "~mini()\n"; }
};
class test
{
public:
    mini ret()
    {
        return *(new mini());
    }
};
int main()
{
    test a;
    a.ret();
    cout << "end of block\n";
}
```

Prints

```
mini()
mini() copy
~mini()
end of block
```

So you're right, the original new'd `mini` is never deleted (leaked).

Comment: Also might help to have a counter in the mini class so you can see explicitly which is created and which is destroyed.

Comment: I think it's worth hammering home that the copy is destroyed before the end of `main` because the copy was not kept and is instantly discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning mini by value, so a second instance gets created for the return (using the copy constructor, nothing printed) and subsequently destroyed when the caller discards it.